# it is good to use angularjs-datatable (Angular 1) instead of only jquery datatable in 2018?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

Here is the angularjs-datatables (Angular 1) link

[angular-datatables v0.6.x](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome)

And Here is jquery-datatables link

[jquery-datatables](https://datatables.net/)

I think there are no any letest update in angularjs-datatables and i used this in my project but it creates many problems in server side configuration and many more..

angular-datatables in latest angular versions like 6,5 it work awesome but it create server side problems in angularjs(1)

so i need suggestion that is better to use only jquery datatables in angularjs project?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery DataTables anlong with AngularJS you should defently use the directives from Angular DataTables 0.6.x. Today it is only maintained for AngularJS, no further active development, but that is not a problem since there were not much left to take care of. Remember, it is only wrapper directives that encapsulate DT. I sincerely doubt you experience serverside problems because of Angular DataTables, it is most likely your own serverside backend that is the problem here.

Answer (score -1):

Is it new app or existing one?

I wouldn't invest my time in AngularJS in late 2018 if it is new app. Good or bad, AngularJS is now legacy.

Can't you find an Angular 2 alternative that will be supported in the  future?

If you already have an AngularJS and need more functionality I don't think that you have alternative except using old modules that you can not expect to be supported anymore and hope they will work fine. It's not the best practice to mix Angular(JS) and jQuery.

Comment: yah it is existing one! and create problem in server side datatables processing

Comment: As both me and Haroldo_OK have pointed it is possible, but not the best practice to mix Angular and jQuery. That's why I would reccommend you to stick to the angular-datatables.

Comment: i want to stick in angularjs-datatables but not going good with server side and another think i m using phalcon php as a backend so its not going good

Comment: So you have to compare the pros and cons of your usecases of having mixed angular and jquery project or to fix the angularjs-datatables problems. There is no universal solution,

Comment: Long term, it would be better to migrate your sistem to modern Angular. It will prevent lots of headaches with unmantained libraries.

Comment: There is no less headaches with Angular than there is with AngularJS.  And as we can see here on stackoverflow, people using Angular have a lot of headaches caused of incompatibility between Angular versions and breaking changes that make their core tools to fail

Comment: The problem is that as time goes along, the compatibility problem will get worse and worse if you keep using an unsupported version of a framework. It's an understandable risk, but one should have that risk in mind.